# Get a list of phased package upgrades for a script (apt vs. update-manager)

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

Hello fellow Ubuntu community,

I stumbled upon the discrepancy between the packages that update-manager offers for upgrade, an those that apt/apt-get shows. That is due to [Ubuntus phased upgrade mechanism](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates) as I know now.

This hinders me, because I need to monitor the clients in our network for their upgrade state. And usually people upgrade just the packages that update-manager offers to upgrade. Leaving our check-scripts with a list of upgradeable packages which are gathered by `apt list --upgradeable`.

What I am looking for is a shell command that lists the phased updates which are held back. I can disply those by running `update-manager --debug`:

```
INFO:root:holding back phased update compiz (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update compiz-core (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update compiz-gnome (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update compiz-plugins-default (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update libcompizconfig0 (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update libdecoration0 (0 < 67)
INFO:root:holding back phased update libpython-stdlib (50 < 93)
INFO:root:holding back phased update libunity-control-center1 (0 < 92)
INFO:root:holding back phased update libunity-core-6.0-9 (0 < 43)
INFO:root:holding back phased update python (50 < 93)
INFO:root:holding back phased update python-minimal (50 < 93)
INFO:root:holding back phased update unity (0 < 43)
INFO:root:holding back phased update unity-control-center (0 < 92)
INFO:root:holding back phased update unity-control-center-faces (0 < 92)
INFO:root:holding back phased update unity-schemas (0 < 43)
INFO:root:holding back phased update unity-services (0 < 43)
```

...but that still pops open update-managers GUI.

Is there any way of aquiring a list of updates which are phased? I Imagine this must be a flag somewhere (in the repository maybe?) that update-manager interpretes.

Comment: `xvfb-run update-manager --debug` might be a solution for you. YOu'd need to install xvfb `sudo apt-get install xvfb`however, since that virtual X11 (framebuffer) is not standard on ubuntu install. But this way you can redirect the graphical output and still get the commandline output for your script.

Comment: Thanks @RobertRiedl - that suppresses the GUI, but leaves the command laying dormant afterwards (propably because it's waiting for input from its GUI). Also - it's pretty slow. I'm rather looking for something that gives me only the updates which aren't held back because of being phased. For example like a (fictious) parameter `apt list --not-phased`.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you: " *Update Manager is currently the only package manager that supports phased updates. Any other update mechanism installs all updates regardless of the Phased-Update-Percentage.*" Quote from [the official Ubuntu page on PhasedUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates)

Comment: do you like this phased mechanism ? because there seems to be a way to disable it... on the other hand, you can always parse the [report on which updates are phased](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/phased-updates.html) and in your check-script, remove those packages ?

Comment: I read about update-manager being the only tool to support this mechanism. But since the article was from 2012, I was hoping this information might be outdated. But I also found nothing else.

Comment: Then maybe parsing the report from canonical is the way to go ?

Comment: Parsing that list is an option to consider - but likely the hardest to implement. I think I'll open a feature request with ubuntu for that apt parameter.
The mechanism itself is IMHO usefull, if it keeps our Ubuntu-clients from installing potentially problematic packages. Some of which actually get revoked.